# What is MultiServerUserRegistry in spring websocket?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

In package `org.springframework.messaging.simp.user` there is a class `MultiServerUserRegistry`.

This class looks like it would work on multi-server application, but I could not find any documentation that could help me understand how it works or how should I use it.

What does this class do and how do I use it? How do I use websocket to work on multi-server application?

Answer (score 4):

The default publish mechanism use a local sessions repository to resolve socket id for a user.
If you are setting up a cluster, you can't use this strategy. We need to use a remote repository.
The removeRepository already exists in Spring as MultiServerUserRegistry. To active it you just have to configure your MessageBrokerRegistry :

```
registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/", "/queue/", "/exchange/")
                .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/unresolved-user")
                .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/user-registry")
```

It works fine for me. I hope that it will help.

Answer (score 2):

According to the MultiServerUserRegistry's JavaDoc, it's an implementation of SimpUserRegistry, which enable us to look up both local and remote user registries.

> SimpUserRegistry that looks up users in a "local" user registry as
>   well as a set of "remote" user registries. The local registry is provided as
>   a constructor argument while remote registries are updated via broadcasts
>   handled by UserRegistryMessageHandler which in turn notifies this
>   registry when updates are received.

Another SimpUserRegistry's implementation is DefaultSimpUserRegistry, which could only get local user.

I read the related source code knowing that when we config setUserRegistryBroadcast in the enableStompBrokerRelay, a MultiServerUserRegistry will be created, and we can get all the users' online state regardless which server they connected in cluster.

Here is the key source code in AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration:

```
@Bean
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public SimpUserRegistry userRegistry() {
    SimpUserRegistry registry = createLocalUserRegistry();
    if (registry == null) {
        registry = createLocalUserRegistry(getBrokerRegistry().getUserRegistryOrder());
    }
    boolean broadcast = getBrokerRegistry().getUserRegistryBroadcast() != null;
    return (broadcast ? new MultiServerUserRegistry(registry) : registry);
}
```

As this function annotated with @Bean, we can get the SimpUserRegistry instance by @Autowired:

```
@Autowired
private SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;
```

Using this interface, we have the ability to:

```
/**
 * Get the user for the given name.
 * @param userName the name of the user to look up
 * @return the user, or {@code null} if not connected
 */
@Nullable
SimpUser getUser(String userName);

/**
 * Return a snapshot of all connected users.
 * <p>The returned set is a copy and will not reflect further changes.
 * @return the connected users, or an empty set if none
 */
Set<SimpUser> getUsers();

/**
 * Return the count of all connected users.
 * @return the number of connected users
 * @since 4.3.5
 */
int getUserCount();

/**
 * Find subscriptions with the given matcher.
 * @param matcher the matcher to use
 * @return a set of matching subscriptions, or an empty set if none
 */
Set<SimpSubscription> findSubscriptions(SimpSubscriptionMatcher matcher);
```

We can use it to get the count of all the online users (by `getUserCount`) in our whole cluster, and detect whether a specific user is online or not (by `getUser`).

As my practice, the following message broker configure is suggested in multi-server scenario:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
            .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/log-unresolved-user")
            .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/log-user-registry")
            .setRelayHost(brokerConfig.getHost())
            .setRelayPort(brokerConfig.getPort())
            .setVirtualHost(brokerConfig.getVirtualHost())
            .setClientLogin(brokerConfig.getUsername())
            .setClientPasscode(brokerConfig.getPassword())
            .setSystemLogin(systemUsername)
            .setSystemPasscode(systemPassword);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works for me. I don't need to maintain online-user set by using handleConnectListener of WebSocketEventListener anymore.